# GridView + Wrap? windows explorer view?

Tags: flutter

The problem with flutter GridView is that it always has a fixed column count, when you resize a GridView, cells are getting resized too.

For Wrap, each cell can have a different size.

Is there a widget like a combination of GridView and Wrap. Just like the windows explorer grid view below, it always tries to fit as many items as possible in a row while maintaining a fixed cell size for each cell. how do i do it in flutter?

[image]

Comment: You want to Gridview `crossAxisCount` is depend on screen size like screen is `small- crossAxisCount : 2`, `normal- crossAxisCount : 5`, `big - crossAxisCount : 7`, `extraLarge - crossAxisCount : 10` etc. this type

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResponsiveGridView` from [responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework) package (it changes quantity of columns depending on the screen size. Or just create your own variable to change quantity of columns dynamically.

Also you can use `Table` widget, it provides a bit more controls of layout than `GridView`.